# Outbound message with inactive user

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

Will it fail? I see many outbound messages in my system definitions that have inactive users as the sender. I wonder if they need  updating/ removing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but why not check by yourself by creating scenario in which an inactive user is sender? If he is then it's pretty clear that you need to update them.

Comment: don't want to mess with the other systems and I can't find it in docs